# Setting CurrentTime not working on HTML5 video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

My video is 36 minutes 19 seconds duration. Can someone help explain why the code below does not jump to the 30 minute mark of the entire video as expected, but instead jumps to around the 12 minute 17 second mark.

```js
var myvideo = document.getElementById('myvideo');

jumplink = document.getElementById('jump');


jumplink.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  myvideo.currentTime = 1800;
  console.log(myvideo.currentTime);
}, false);
```

```html
<video autoplay="" controls="controls" id="myvideo" preload="auto" src="/videos/video.mp4"></video>

<p><button id="jump">Jump</button></p>
```

Comment: I suspect the timestamps are messed up in the video file.  Can you upload it somewhere?  Also, what's up with the successive calls to `play()`, `pause()`, then set the time, and then immediately `play()`?

Comment: @mplungjan He's not pausing though, not really.  He's playing, pausing, setting the current time, and then playing again.  There's no need for that.  If he wants to play, then he should remove the first two play/pause.

Comment: @Rogerto, what does `console.log(myvideo.duration);` tell us when you click - BEFORE you skip

Comment: @mplungjan console.log(myvideo.duration) shows 2179.157333

Comment: OK, then that is not it

Comment: have you encoded the video with the MOOV atom at the front (in ffmpeg the faststart option), so it has the metadata available. if not, until the file has fully loaded seeking will not be accurate. failing that... see the answer below (waiting for loadedmetadata)